# How to capture colored terminal (ANSI) output and log it preserving colors

Tags: html, terminal, stdout, ansi-escape, terminal-color

I had a need to capture the colored output of a long-running command line program, so I could easily share it with colleagues. Specifically, I'm running `vagrant up`, which generates colorful and useful output and I need to save this in a convenient format. My best solution so far uses two programs, `aha` and `script`, which are available as mainstream packages.

`aha` takes ANSI escape sequences and converts them to HTML markup. `script` fools your program into thinking it's outputting to your screen and not STDOUT, which normally disables color for many programs

I run my command in two steps:

1. `script -q -c "vagrant up" temp.txt` (`-q` removes status messages and `-c` tells script to run the command)
2. `cat temp.txt | aha --black > output.htm` (the `--black` flag makes the HTML background dark)

I'm pretty happy so far, but maybe this can be combined into one line? Any thoughts? Or better commands I could use? I'm aware the python `ansi2html`, but this seemed easier.

Comment: Looks like `ansi2html` relies on redirecting input, unlike `script`.  I'd just combine the two steps you use as a shell script which uses a temporary file for `temp.txt` and enforces `/dev/tty` as input for the `script` command.  A little more complicated than you have it here...